# attr() not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, attr

after browsing some similar question on here I couldn't find anything to help me fix my problem. In Chrome it works, get to IE and I get "aN,AN,NAN"

the HTML

```
<div class="dateSelect">
  <div class="prev">
      <a class="prevMonth" name="05,27,2013">month</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

the jQuery

```
$(".dateSelect a").click(function(event){
        var dateParam = $(this).attr('name');

        alert("link was clicked and value of NAME is: "+dateParam);
        dateChange(dateParam);
        event = event || window.event;
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
```

In Chrome it grabs the date "05,27,2013" but IE it's "aN,aN,NaN"
I have a sneaky suspicion IE doesn't like attr(). If that's the case, is there an alternative way? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? and what version of IE?

Comment: Oh, sorry, forgot to mention haha. Using a local copy, 1.9.1 and using IE9. Need it to work for IE8 and 7 too

Comment: Have you tried `this.name`. Since it is a valid attribute for anchor tag I am assuming it must give you the name correctly everywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`name` has the same rules as `id`, can't start with a number and no special chars, and IE hates it...

in this case, use `data-` attributes, like:

```
<a class="prevMonth" data-name="05,27,2013">month</a>
```

and from your script get it through:

`$(this).attr("data-name")` or `$(this).data("name")`.

it even works with IE6 (if you still using version 1.x of jQuery) :)

Comment: Yes, it worked, and it helped me to further troubleshoot what else is going on now! Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: But isn't data- attributes only available with browsers that support html5? I thought ie does not support html5

Comment: `data-` is just an attribute, and older browser do not know what to do with them, so it get's ignored, but `data-` is not only for HTML5 enabled browser, is a simply way to pass more information...